# SQL server connection failed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm having trouble with my web application developped in ASP.net.

I'm actually adding features to it, the previous version is working fine.

It's a merchant web site, and when an user have more than one item in the cart, the issue appears.
On this case (exemple of two items), this code is called 2 times :

```
System.Configuration.Configuration WebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString = WebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];
SqlConnection connection;

connection = new SqlConnection(connString.ConnectionString);

if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    connection.Open();
```

The first time it pass, but the second I get the error "Échec de l'ouverture de session de l'utilisateur 'IIS APPPOOL\XXXXX'." what means "Failed to open the session of user 'IIS APPPOOL\XXXXX'.".

I use the same part of code for all my connections and never got this issue.

I thought about limited connections number, but its set to illimited in sql server.

Do you have any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: Why would you check the state of a connection immediately after creating it?

Comment: The app is not mine, I dont know the reason of this part. As I can see in debug mode, it's always closed after creating.

Answer (score 1):

I think your sqlconnection is not closed properly after each call. Try this -

```
string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
     connection.Open();
     //your code goes here
}
```

** the using block will automatically dispose any open sqlconnection.

Comment: It still throws the same exception. By the way, the part of code i posted is at the beggining of a method.

Comment: @EdouardGarraud could you post the code of the method? edit you question and add the code there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the credentials in web.config. 
I would also change the connection string getter for something like

```
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Also, remember to include it in a "using" block or try/finally, where you can safely close&dispose your connection and related objects.

Comment: Actually it uses Windows authentification: <authentication mode="Windows"/>

Comment: This line is not related to database authentication, but to website authentication.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: So I just have no "credentials" specified in the config file. But I think this is not the cause of the problem, the connection works in all other cases.

Comment: That's exactly your problem. You need to specify a connection string and proper credentials in your web.config, under the connection strings section. Your application is trying to log in ddbb with the app pool identity.

Comment: I read some infos about this element in config and it looks like the identity of the user of the website, not the website itself. And why have I never got any problem without this element set, even with the same part of code ?

Comment: Look, I can't tell the details because I don't have the code, but if you have this two lines of code:
    System.Configuration.Configuration WebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString = WebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];

And there is no connection string in config, don't you think that something is really wrong?

Comment: For sure there is the connectionString in config file:     <add connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=XXXXX;Integrated Security=True;" name="connectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>